# Olympiad Number Theory Problem Regarding Residue Classes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Let R be the set of all the remainders when 2<sup>i</sup> is divided by 1000 for all i in natural numbers. Let S be the sum of all elements of R. Find S mod 1000

I found this problem in an IOQM (The indian equivalent of AIME) mock test paper. I have been trying this for a long time but haven't reached anywhere. Does someone have an approach?

Answer (score 3):

Since $1000 = 2^3 5^3$, we can work modulo each and then combine the results. Modulo $2^3$ the behavior of $2^i$ is trivial - it's $1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0...$. Modulo $5^3$, we just need to know that it's $2^0,  2^1, ..., 2^n$, where $2^{n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod {5^3}$ and there are no repetitions. Then the sum is $2^{n+1}-1\equiv 0 \pmod {5^3}$. So the possible pairs are: $(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4), (0, 2^3), ..., (0, 2^{n+3})$. All of them excluding the first three have sum $0 \pmod {1000}$, so the answer is $1+2+4=7$. If you don't consider $0$ a natural number the answer is $6$.